# Query to Get the "prix_total" per month in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a table with the following attributes, "id_commande, id_client, id_agent, D_commande, Heure_commande, prix_total".
D_commande represents DATE OF SALE
prix_total represents the price of a sale.

[image]

when I tried to create a Query to Get the "prix_total" per month. I struggled.
notice that I tried this query but I don't get the correct result:

```
SELECT sum(prix_total)
FROM commande
GROUP BY (
     SELECT strftime('%y','D_commande')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m',D_commande) AS month, 
       SUM(prix_total) AS prix_total
  FROM commande 
 GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m',D_commande)
 ORDER BY month
```

in order to get the result partitioned by months

Comment: you're welcome @theunknownxD , good luck !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(prix_total)
FROM commande
GROUP BY strftime('%Y',D_commande) 
       , strftime('%m',D_commande)
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e4f3f7ac17d374449ea13fb9ac9b85b2)

And also you can order by year and month:

```
ORDER BY strftime('%Y',D_commande) 
       , strftime('%m',D_commande)
```